# Push notifications not received

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

I am implementing push notifications in my app, everything seems fine but the push notifications doesn't received at my device.

I got the response when fire a notification from the URL as above;

"Connected to APNS Message successfully delivered".

But after that there is no notification at my device. Please suggest me how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

At first check out you **Payload** which describes the nature of your push notification means whether it should be text message or an alert or a badge on the app icon. So we need to set it properly in **JSON's** formate. check it out first ,

Then

Go through this nice tutorial by Ray Wenderlich forum, 
Surely you will found some little missed field or step,

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

Comment: i have faced the same problem before, So i tried with repeating the process from creating new CSR and PEM files and the assigning that new provisioning profile, And its done. I will suggest go through EACH step again with cool .

Answer (score 0):

I got same error because i was writing wrong device token please check your device token @" < XXx XXXX xxx..> "  changed to @"XXX XXX.."
Or just follow steps

In app delegate

in didlaunch

```
// Register for sound and alert push notifications.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    // Check if the app was launched in response to the user tapping on a
    // push notification. If so, we add the new message to the data model.
    if (launchOptions != nil)
    {
        NSDictionary* dictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        if (dictionary != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Launched from push notification: %@", dictionary);
        //  [self addMessageFromRemoteNotification:dictionary updateUI:NO];
        }
    }


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Apple Push notifications

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    // We have received a new device token. This method is usually called right
    // away after you've registered for push notifications, but there are no
    // guarantees. It could take up to a few seconds and you should take this
    // into consideration when you design your app. In our case, the user could
    // send a "join" request to the server before we have received the device
    // token. In that case, we silently send an "update" request to the server
    // API once we receive the token.

    NSString* oldToken = [self deviceToken];

    NSString* newToken = [deviceToken description];
    newToken = [newToken stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    newToken = [newToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", newToken);

    [self setDeviceToken:newToken];

    // If the token changed and we already sent the "join" request, we should
    // let the server know about the new device token.
//  if ([dataModel joinedChat] && ![newToken isEqualToString:oldToken])
//  {
//      [self postUpdateRequest];
//  }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    // If we get here, the app could not obtain a device token. In that case,
    // the user can still send messages to the server but the app will not
    // receive any push notifications when other users send messages to the
    // same chat room.

    NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo
{
    // This method is invoked when the app is running and a push notification
    // is received. If the app was suspended in the background, it is woken up
    // and this method is invoked as well. We add the new message to the data
    // model and add it to the ChatViewController's table view.

    NSLog(@"Received APNS notification: %@", userInfo);
    [self log:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Received APNS notification: %@", userInfo]];

    UIAlertView* nofity = [[ UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"APNS" message:@"Test Successfull" delegate:nil
cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [nofity show];

//  [self addMessageFromRemoteNotification:userInfo updateUI:YES];
}



- (NSString*)deviceToken
{
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"DeviceTokenKey"];
}

- (void)setDeviceToken:(NSString*)token
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:token forKey:@"DeviceTokenKey"];
}

- (NSString*)udid
{
    UIDevice* device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    return [device.uniqueIdentifier stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
}
```

**Obtain the device token from above code.**

**Testing**
Pass the device token to the [Push me baby app](https://github.com/stefanhafeneger/PushMeBaby)

Answer (score 0):

Check the following

1. Are you getting the push token. If yes, Remove the spaces, and <, > from the push token.
2. Check if the device is connected to the internet
3. Check if notification is enabled (either banner or popup) in Settings -> Notifications -> Your application -> Select banner or alert (popup).

Most probably, any of this would be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

One simple trick: 
I had the same problem, double checked everything, recreated pem, etc. but could't get it going after my last dev cert timed out and I recreated it. Before the app was working over months.

In the end what helped was really wipe it from the phone and reinstall it.
Seems that some of the stored data was somehow corrupt...

Remember that the app will then register with a new token.